# Best Format to Bulk INSERT/UPDATE Data to SQL SERVER using C#

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, c#

Can anyone tell me what is best way to bulk insert/update data to SQL SERVER 2012 using C#? I have an excel file which I am passing as TVP(table value parameter) to a SP. But this is little bit slower. Any hint will appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what the procedure does with the data once it's on the SQL side?

Comment: @JonSeigel, Actually from excel I am extracting lot of tables which I am passing in SP as a TVP. Inside SP, I am simply updating or inserting these into my db tables using the TVPs. There may be around 10 to 15 tables come into play.

Answer (score 1):

What about "NO FORMAT"? Use SqlBulkCopy to dump the data into a temp table. No need to put a file in a place the server can read at all.

Comment: Actually I need to extract data from an excel file at runtime and need to be format this excel file before inserting/updating into my db tables. Currently, I am using TVP. SqlBulkCopy only works with insert

Comment: Ah, no. It does not only work with insert - yes, you can only directly insert, but that can go into a temporary table for further processing. THis is what I do.